# State machines and control signals in a simple CPU

Tags: digital-logic, cpu

Having built the CPU specified in "The Elements of Computing Systems", I thought I'd try to design a simple 8-bit CPU myself as a fun challenge, with a view to implementing it on an FPGA. However, the book above makes several concessions, and left me with a few questions regarding "real" CPU design.

Say I have twelve different state machines (each for a different instruction) that, in some state, need to manipulate a 2-bit register select line on my CPU to get data into the correct register. How should each of those FSMs physically connect to those control lines? I thought of simply using a multiplexer, but then the question becomes, how do I properly feed the output selection lines on that MUX to control which input becomes the output? I understand well how a MUX works in a simple scenario, but the interconnections become difficult to understand once you throw in a bunch of state machines.

I've read [Finite State Machines for Simple CPUs](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs150/fa05/CLD_Supplement/chapter11/chapter11.doc3.html)  - which does a good job of discussing the role of state machines and their basic operation in a CPU, but doesn't touch on the physical implementation.

In summary, I can construct FSMs, an ALU and so on, but I'm confused as to how the FSMs needed to affect the instructions physically connect to the control lines that actually instruct the ALU/registers/etc.

Comment: why a different state machine per instruction?  what if you did one state machine that handled all of them it might take different paths here and there.

Comment: in any case, assuming you only handle one instruction at a time, only one state machine is operating the other are idle yes?  so you can combine the shared control lines with that assumption if any machine wants this signal asserted then assert it because only one will at any time.

Comment: I think this overstates the role of state machines in CPU design. Pipelined processors hardly use them for instruction flow, by definition. As an aside, some designers do everything with state machines, some use them rarely and when absolutely necessary. Try to be the latter, you will produce better designs for simpler and more maintainable circuits. Sorry if this contradicts what you've taken from your book.

Comment: If you want some excellent background insight into elementary 8-bit CPU design then take a look at Ben Eater's fabulous youtube series "Building an 8-bit breadboard computer!" ... https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU

Comment: @old_timer - I forgot to mention I assumed in my question one FSM per instruction, but I wasn't certain that was necessary (it seemed a little overkill). Thanks for pointing out that it's not

Comment: @TonyM - that's interesting, thanks. I'm vaguely aware of pipelining and its advantages, but omitted it in my considerations because I believed it would reduce complexity (perhaps incorrectly). In honesty, I don't have a favoured approach, I'd just like to understand how to make it work _at all_ :)

Comment: @Wossname - I didn't even know about that series. Thanks!